# Display a random product thumbnail for a product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I am trying to pull a random product thumbnail to display as an image on one of my pages. I can't seem to find a way that works, and have tried the solutions from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218283/woocommerce-show-random-product-thumbnail-from-specific-product-category) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805105/woocommerce-get-product-image-from-category-id) post.

It would be beneficial to echo it out in a div as well.

Here is what I am currently trying but I'm still unsure how to do this.

**functions.php:**

```
function get_random_thumbnails_for_reg(){
    if(is_page(381)){

        $args = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',   
                    'terms' => 'allison-1000-gm-duramax-series'  
                )
            )
        );

        $random_products = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ( $random_products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
        ?>
            <div id="randomPic"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
        <?php 
         endforeach; 
         wp_reset_postdata();

    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'get_random_thumbnails_for_reg', 50);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after some testing I got it working in a different modular way. I have created a custom shortcode that displays randomly one product thumbnail based on a product category**.

This shortcode has 2 argument:

- The product category slug: **`cat`**
- The image **`size`** (can be: `'shop_thumbnail'`, `'shop_catalog'` or `'shop_single'`)

Then I use this short code in your custom function hooked in `wp_footer` action hook.

Here is that code:

```
// Creating a shortcode that displays a random product image/thumbail
if( !function_exists('custom_shortcode_random_thumbnail') ) {

    function custom_shortcode_random_thumbnail( $atts ) {

        // Shortcode attributes
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'cat'   => '', // product category shortcode attribute
                'size'      => 'shop_thumbnail', // Default image size
            ),
            $atts, 'random_thumbnail'
        );

        // Get products randomly (from a specific product category)
        $random_post = get_posts( array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'orderby'   => 'rand',
            'post_status' => 'published',
            'tax_query' => array( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $atts['cat'],
            ) )
        ) );
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product($random_post[0]->ID);

        // The Product permalink
        $product_permalink = $product->get_permalink();

        // The Product image. Size can be: 1. 'shop_thumbnail', 2. 'shop_catalog' or 3. 'shop_single'
        $product_image = $product->get_image( $atts['size'] );

        // The output
        return '<div id="random-pic"><a href="' . $product_permalink . '">' . $product_image . '</a></div>';
    }
    add_shortcode( 'random_thumbnail', 'custom_shortcode_random_thumbnail' );
}


// Using the shortcode to display a random product image
function get_random_thumbnails_for_reg(){
    // Only for page ID 381
    if( ! is_page( 381 ) ) return;

    echo do_shortcode( "[random_thumbnail cat='clothing']" );
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'get_random_thumbnails_for_reg', 50);
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works

Comment: Thankyou! I have since shifted over to some spreadsheet work but will test this and mark it as correct as soon as I can

Comment: how to check stock status and display random product which are in stock